# Will I go to Jahannam?

Tags: salat, halal-haram, day-of-judgement, family

Assalamu aliakum,

I know god is the one to make the final judgement, but I've a question. I keep a strained relationship with my father. I'm 25 now. My father does not go to work nor he looks after me, my sister and my mother. All he does is say no to almost everything in our lives, but he let us go somewhere if we want. But if I want to buy a phone, he would say no. My father is the eldest one of his brothers and sisters, and he is cheated by them in family property and so and so. He always says that he wanted a son not daughters. He always shout at me curse as well, well I do the same too. Because I think the man who does not take care of me have no authority to shout at me. He has told me many times that he've not considered me his daughter....

I can't control my anger... what do I do... I know it is not good to shout at father or curse him.... But what am I supposed to do... Also I speak to myself... I want to get rid of this behavior.. he has once called me mad...  Is there any ayah to get rid of speaking to my selves... and what am I supposed to do when my father shout at me... (Dont tell me keep quite, boz I have failed a thousand times.. )

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. Please note, we are a Q&A site dedicated to the *academic* study of Islam, not a typical Islamic forum. We are poorly-suited to answer open-ended questions seeking general advice, which you would better ask of someone you trust (friends, family, imam) than random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: See also the related meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/22

Comment: honestly this is a question only Allah and the Nabi PBUH can and could have answered

Answer (score 1):

Vaaleykum assalyam. Dear sister, this life is just an exam for mankind. Patience is the best policy. You should never shout at your father no matter what kind of personality he is. Allah (SWT) is testing You and He wants to see how You can behave. Remember, Allah (SWT) tests because He loves You. If you fail to behave as behaved our Prophet ( peace be upon him ), Allah will get angry on You. You are born to worship the God and live by the rules of Islam. Patience is the only thing You can do. May Allah guide You.